Does wheat flour make home-made cheese taste like chedder?
When you mix wheat flour with milk, before curdling the milk, does the resulting cheese taste like cheddar cheese?
I made some home-made glue for a paper mache art project using wheat paste and I noticed that the glue smelled very strong of cheddar cheese after being inside of a refrigerator for more than 3 weeks (I discarded the old smelly glue; I did not use it)
I imagine that the micro-organisms inside of the wheat paste glue are the same as those used for American cheddar.

"When you mix wheat flour with milk" -- AFAIK, generally you don't do that when making cheese.

Generally what will have happened is that you contaminated your glue with a bacterium or fungus that to you smells like cheese - might well be one of the Candida or Staphylococcus groups.

No, wheat flour doesn't make homemade cheese taste like cheddar. Cheddar's flavor comes from specific cultures and aging processes, not from adding flour.

Cheddar's flavor comes from cultures, aging and cheddaring
